# Максимально допустимая температура видеокарты GTX 1050 на ноутбуке с плохим охлаждением

Tags: железо, видеокарта

Решил я повысить максимальную температуру видеокарты на 5+ градусов, мол ничего не должно случится, но проблема в том что максимальная температура и так уже была 80*С. Вопрос какая максимально допустимая температура для видеокарты GTX 1050 что бы она не начала плавится и ещё через пол года не зажарилась?
(ноутбуку 3 года, термопасту менял)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все довольно просто идем на [сайт](https://www.nvidia.com/ru-ru/geforce/10-series/) и смотрим [табличку](https://www.nvidia.com/ru-ru/geforce/10-series/#1050-ti-spec) спецификаций:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть написано про температуру [1](https://www.wepc.com/tips/optimal-cpu-gpu-temperature-gaming/)